# "use client" returns a blank page in Next.js 13

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, frontend, next.js13

"I'm using Next.js 13.3.0 and when I try to use 'use client' at the beginning of the page, it returns an error and a blank page."
[image]
[image]

Note: It is mandatory to use "use client" in components that use state or useEffect.

Thank you for your help.

I would like to use useEffect, but it returned an error.

Comment: Could you provide relevant source code to help debug your issue? Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Error corrected, I updated all the dependencies of my project and ran it again and it worked perfectly, thank you!